# Why do xsl template rules not apply on elements inserted with XSLT instructions?

Tags: plone, diazo

I want to insert e.g. `#content-core` in a given part of the theme and apply some xsl instruction in the elements under `#content-core`

If we use the following scenario A rules, the `a` elements under `#content-core` will be replaced as expected:

**Scenario A**

```xml
<replace css:theme="#target_id" css:content="#content-core" />
<xsl:template match="a">REPLACED_LINK</xsl:template>
```

This scenario A is not what I need. I need a scenario with elements inserted with xsl instructions.

When I insert the element with the xsl instruction as follows, then the `a` elements under `#content-core` won't be replaced. Why?

**Scenario B**

```xml
<replace css:theme-children="#target_id">
    <xsl:copy-of css:select="#content-core"/>
</replace>
<xsl:template match="a">REPLACED_LINK</xsl:template>
```

If the `<xsl:apply-templates />` instruction is also used as suggested, then the resulting theme will have two inserted `#content-core` elements: in the first the `a` elements won't be replaced and in the second they will be replaced.

**Scenario C**

```xml
<replace css:theme-children="#target_id">
    <xsl:copy-of css:select="#content-core"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />  <!-- as suggested by SteveM, see answers -->
</replace>
<xsl:template match="a">REPLACED_LINK</xsl:template>
```

**The files I am using**

Here I copy the files `rules.xml` and `index.html` which I am using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <theme href="index.html" />

    <!--replace css:theme="#target_id" css:content="#content-core" /-->
    <replace css:theme-children="#target_id">
        <xsl:copy-of css:select="#content-core"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />  <!-- as suggested by SteveM, see answers -->
    </replace>

    <xsl:template match="a">REPLACED_LINK</xsl:template>
</rules>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body><div id="target_id"/></body>
</html>
```

**Some hints that might help**

Trying to understand why this is not working as I expected I've been debugging on diazo's `rules.py` and `compiler.py` and I found that the `compiled_doc` returned by `compiler.compile_theme(...)` differs as follows:

`compiled_doc` of scenario A:

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id = 'content-core']"/>
```

`compiled_doc` of scenario B:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of css:select="#content-core" select="descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'content-core']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

After the call of `apply_rules(...)` in `rules.py` the `rules_doc` differ (scenario A and B) as follows:

```xml
5c5,8
< <xsl:apply-templates xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" xmlns:esi="http://www.edge-delivery.org/esi/1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" select="//*[@id = 'content-core']"></xsl:apply-templates>
---
> 
>         <xsl:copy-of xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" css:select="#content-core" select="descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'content-core']"></xsl:copy-of>
>         <xsl:apply-templates xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"></xsl:apply-templates>
> 
8,9c11,14
< 
<     <diazo:replace css:theme="#target_id" css:content="#content-core" xml:id="r2" theme="descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'target_id']" content="//*[@id = 'content-core']"><diazo:synthetic xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic" xmlns:esi="http://www.edge-delivery.org/esi/1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"><xsl:apply-templates xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" select="//*[@id = 'content-core']"></xsl:apply-templates></diazo:synthetic><diazo:matches><diazo:xmlid themeid="r1">idm16926224-index.html</diazo:xmlid></diazo:matches></diazo:replace>
---
>     <diazo:replace css:theme="#target_id" xml:id="r2" theme="descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'target_id']"><diazo:synthetic>
>         <xsl:copy-of xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" css:select="#content-core" select="descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'content-core']"></xsl:copy-of>
>         <xsl:apply-templates xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"></xsl:apply-templates>
>     </diazo:synthetic><diazo:matches><diazo:xmlid themeid="r1">idm16375952-index.html</diazo:xmlid></diazo:matches></diazo:replace>
```

Comment: It's now unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @SteveM I reformulated my question. It's now clearer?

Comment: @SteveM What I need is: given a document tree like `x > y` state a diazo rule to substitute the element `y` with the tree `y' > z` and a second rule to substitute the inserted element `z` with the tree `z' > w`.